# Regression Equation when multiple DV's (varying years)?

Tags: regression, spss

I have a research question that is asking how perception of quality change over time. So participants answered what they believed quality is at Year 1, Year 5, Year 10, etc.

How do I create a regression equation to capture the line that represents beliefs in quality over time? So x axis is time and y axis is quality. What would the SPSS code be or what type of regression would I set up?

IV: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40
DV: Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 Q_4 Q_5 Q_6 Q_7 Q_8
100 participants.